# Найти и выделить в элементе GridView(DevExpress) строку с необходимой информацией

Tags: c#, gridview

```
        int Index, ValueToFocus;
        Index = gridView2.FocusedRowHandle;
        ValueToFocus = Convert.ToInt32(gridView2.GetRowCellValue(Index, "Код"));
        for (int i = 0; i < gridView3.RowCount; i++)
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(gridView3.GetRowCellValue(i ,"Код")) == ValueToFocus)
            {
                gridView3.SelectRow(i);
                gridView3.IsRowSelected(i);
                break;
            }
        }
```

Написал код, который должен находить в gridView3 строку, в которой столбец "Код" будет иметь нужное мне значение(ValueToFocus). Затем программа должна выделять эту строку. Я использую SelectRow().Строка не выделяется и последующая проверка IsRowSelected() выдаёт значение false. Как исправить, чтобы в gridView3 выделялась нужная строка?

Comment: в отладчике смотрели if выполняется или всегда мимо? насколько я помню, таким образом вы переберете все строки грида, даже те которые не отображаются в данный момент. Строка, которая должна быть выделена, в этот момент в видимой части грида? Пробовали без всяких условий таким образом выделить любую строку, выделяет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот решение проблемы:

```
gridView3.OptionsSelection.MultiSelect = true;
gridView3.SelectRow(i);
bool torf = gridView3.IsRowSelected(i);
```

Таким образом torf показывает true и строка выделяется.